# Composer get stuck while generating autoload files

Tags: composer-php

After an update to the new Composer version

```
a2a70380c14a20b3f611d849eae7342f2e35c763 2013-10-21 09:51:22
```

Composer get stuck while generating autoload files. CPU is running on 100%, but no files are generated.

I am using XAMPP  PHP version 5.5.3. I didn't have any problem before.

Comment: The problem is in a directory junction. If you run this new version witin the junction directory it will get stuck.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "directory junction". If this is an error inside Composer, you should open an issue on their Github page to get this fixed.